# Getting Tcl error while working with python Tkinter command for GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget

I am working on a GUI that downsamples videos in a folder that the user inputs.
This is the basic framework:
1.On button click the user inputs the path/directory of the videos
2.I have a downsample function that takes this input (path) of the user and downsamples the videos.
EDIT: I have seen similar answers under the same error, I have tried the solution but it's not working and was giving different errors. So, instead, I'm posting this to avoid confusion and would like to learn how to fix this particular one.
This is what I have:

```py
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import *

from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile 

root = Tk() 
root.geometry('200x100') 

def open_file(): 
    file = askdirectory() 
    if file is not None:
        return file#add if directory is not correct option
btn = Button(root, text ='Open', command = lambda:open_file())
btn.pack(side = TOP, pady = 10) 
#mainloop() 
def downsamplevideos(open_file):
    for video in os.listdir(open_file):
        input_file_name=video
        (
            ffmpeg
            .input('/Users/lala/Desktop/checktwo/{}'.format(input_file_name))
            .filter_('scale', 640, 360)
            .output("/Users/lala/Desktop/videos/downsampleda{}".format(input_file_name))
            .run(capture_stdout=True, capture_stderr=True)
        )
btn2 = Button(root, text="Select",command=lambda:downsamplevideos(open_file()))
btn2.pack(side = TOP, pady = 10)


This is opening a window with two button. But it is not working, that is it is not downsampling. Can anyone help me with this implementation?
```

Comment: For `btn2` you set the parent to `master`, which is not defined. I think you mean `root` and this may be what causes the error

Comment: @Henry thank you for pointing out.I edited it in my code

Comment: @Henry It is not working.Do you know more about this?

Comment: Is this a problem with the downsampling or tkinter?

Comment: @Henry downsampling function works separetly. I am unable to work it  with tkinter. The window opens and then I can choose the folder.It asks twice and then it stops.It doesn't downsample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `open_file` after pressing the open button, the file path is not stored anywhere. This can be resolved by creating a global variable `directory`, which will store the file path so it can be used in `downsamplevideos`.

```
directory = None
def open_file(): 
    file = askdirectory() 
    if file is not None:
        global directory
        directory = file
btn = Button(root, text ='Open', command = lambda:open_file())
btn.pack(side = TOP, pady = 10) 
#mainloop() 
def downsamplevideos():
    global directory
    for video in os.listdir(directory):
        input_file_name=video
        (
            ffmpeg
            .input('/Users/lala/Desktop/checktwo/{}'.format(input_file_name))
            .filter_('scale', 640, 360)
            .output("/Users/lala/Desktop/videos/downsampleda{}".format(input_file_name))
            .run(capture_stdout=True, capture_stderr=True)
        )
btn2 = Button(root, text="Select",command=lambda:downsamplevideos())
btn2.pack(side = TOP, pady = 10)
```

Comment: Thank you:)) This works great:) Plus, I learned something more on Tkinter.Thank you again!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)